# Guacamole: Multiple simultaneous vnc connections over websocket close each other

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, guacamole

We are using guacamole to access remote desktop in web-browser.
We try to use websocket-tunnel for better performance, but if I open two tab in my browser connecting to two different vnc server through same guacd server, one page get frozen(websocket stop send/receive any messages), the other get error like: 776 and disconnected. But if we use http servlet seems this get resolved. Anyone encounter similar issue?
Here are my setup.

1. guacamole-js was used in web side.
2. We use x11vnc, guacd installed with same linux box
3. We developed two endpoints use spring-boot: websocket-tunnel by extending GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint,

   ```
   @Component
   public class MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint extends GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint {@Autowired
   MyGuacamoleAutoProperties myGuacamoleAutoProperties;

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint.class);

   public myGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint() {
       logger.info("MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint constructed!");
   }

   @Override
   protected GuacamoleTunnel createTunnel(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) throws GuacamoleException{

       Map<String, List<String>> parameterMap = session.getRequestParameterMap();

       String vid = getFirstValue(parameterMap,myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getVncPortParaName());
       String host = getFirstValue(parameterMap,myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getVncHostParaName());

       // Get client information
       GuacamoleClientInformation info = new GuacamoleClientInformation();
       // Create our configuration
       GuacamoleConfiguration config  = new GuacamoleConfiguration();
       config.setProtocol("vnc");
       config.setParameter("hostname", host);
       config.setParameter("port", vid);
       config.setParameter("password", myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getVncPassword());

       String guacdHost=host;
       // Connect to guacd
       GuacamoleTunnel tunnel;
       if(myGuacamoleAutoProperties.isUseStandaloneGuacd()){
           guacdHost=myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getGuacdHost();
       }
       GuacamoleSocket socket = new ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket(
               new InetGuacamoleSocket(guacdHost,myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getGuacdPort()), config);
       tunnel=new SimpleGuacamoleTunnel(socket);
       GuacamoleTunnel monitoredTunnel = new DelemyingGuacamoleTunnel(tunnel) {

           @Override
           public GuacamoleReader acquireReader() {
               logger.debug("Open tunnel on port: '" + getPort() + "', uuid: '" + getUUID() + "' and connection_id: '" + ((ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket)getSocket()).getConnectionID() + "'.");
               return super.acquireReader();
           }

           @Override
           public void close() throws GuacamoleException {
               logger.debug("Close tunnel on port: '" + getPort() + "', uuid: '" + getUUID() + "' and connection_id: '" + ((ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket)getSocket()).getConnectionID() + "'.");
               super.close();
           }

           /**
            * Get the Guac Port from the Tunnel->Socket->Configuration.
            *
            * @return Guac Port
            */
           private String getPort() {
               return ((ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket) getSocket()).getConfiguration().getParameter("port");
           }
       };

       return monitoredTunnel;
   }

   private String getFirstValue(Map<String, List<String>> map, String key) {
       List<String> values = map.get(key);
       return values != null ? values.get(0) : null;
   }
   ```

http-servlet tunnel by extending GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet

```
@Component
public class MyGuacamoleTunnelServlet extends GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet {

    @Autowired
    MyGuacamoleAutoProperties myGuacamoleAutoProperties;

    @Override
    protected GuacamoleTunnel doConnect(HttpServletRequest request) throws GuacamoleException {
        String vid = request.getParameter(myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getVncPortParaName());
        String host = request.getParameter(myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getVncHostParaName());

        // Create our configuration
        GuacamoleConfiguration config = new GuacamoleConfiguration();
        config.setProtocol("vnc");
        config.setParameter("hostname", host);
        config.setParameter("port", vid);
        //config.setParameter("user",  request.getParameter("user"));
        config.setParameter("password", myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getVncPassword());

        // Connect to guacd
        String guacdHost=host;
        GuacamoleTunnel tunnel;
        if(myGuacamoleAutoProperties.isUseStandaloneGuacd()){
            guacdHost=myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getGuacdHost();
        }

        GuacamoleSocket socket = new ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket(
                new InetGuacamoleSocket(guacdHost,myGuacamoleAutoProperties.getGuacdPort()), config);
        tunnel=new SimpleGuacamoleTunnel(socket);
        // Return a new tunnel which uses the connected socket
        return tunnel;
    }
}
```

Guacd logs here:

```
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Protocol "vnc" selected
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Connection ID is "$7d545e7e-0a29-40e5-a4a3-9964fa07b22b"
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.8)
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: We have 1 security types to read
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 0) Received security type 1
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Selecting security type 1 (0/1 in the list)
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Selected Security Scheme 1
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: No authentication needed
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: VNC authentication succeeded
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Desktop name "vnchost:0"
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Connected to VNC server, using protocol version 3.8
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: VNC server default format:
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]:  32 bits per pixel.
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]:  Least significant byte first in each pixel.
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]:  TRUE colour: max red 255 green 255 blue 255, shift red 16 green 8 blue 0
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Starting client
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: client2server supported messages (bit flags)
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 00: 00ff 0081 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 08: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 10: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 18: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0004
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: server2client supported messages (bit flags)
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 00: 001f 0080 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 08: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 10: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: 18: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0004
Jan 25 04:32:58 vnchost guacd[105232]: Connected to Server "unknown (LibVNCServer 0.9.9)”

Jan 25 04:36:28 vnchost guacd[105538]: Protocol "vnc" selected
Jan 25 04:36:28 vnchost guacd[105538]: Connection ID is "$6fd98484-1dd0-4c66-aa04-6c358cd30548"
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.8)
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: We have 1 security types to read
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 0) Received security type 1
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Selecting security type 1 (0/1 in the list)
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Selected Security Scheme 1
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: No authentication needed
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: VNC authentication succeeded
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Desktop name "vnchost:2"
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Connected to VNC server, using protocol version 3.8
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: VNC server default format:
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]:  32 bits per pixel.
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]:  Least significant byte first in each pixel.
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]:  TRUE colour: max red 255 green 255 blue 255, shift red 16 green 8 blue 0
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Starting client
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: client2server supported messages (bit flags)
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 00: 00ff 0081 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 08: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 10: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 18: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0004
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: server2client supported messages (bit flags)
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 00: 001f 0080 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 08: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 10: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0000
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: 18: 0000 0000 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 0000 0004
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Connected to Server "unknown (LibVNCServer 0.9.9)"
Jan 25 04:36:29 vnchost guacd[105538]: Connection aborted
Jan 25 04:36:30 vnchost guacd[105538]: Client disconnected
Jan 25 04:36:30 vnchost kernel: guacd[105538]: segfault at 1000003f8 ip 00007fbfce7bdc24 sp 00007ffe0d31c990 error 4 in libguac-client-vnc.so.0.0.0[7fbfce7b2000+f000]
Jan 25 04:36:30 vnchost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 105538 (guacd) of user 0 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Jan 25 04:36:30 vnchost abrt-server: Executable '/usr/local/sbin/guacd' doesn't belong to any package and ProcessUnpackaged is set to 'no'
Jan 25 04:36:43 vnchost guacd[105232]: Client is not responding.
Jan 25 04:36:43 vnchost guacd[105232]: Client disconnected
Jan 25 04:36:43 vnchost kernel: guacd[105232]: segfault at 1000003f8 ip 00007fbfce7bdc24 sp 00007ffe0d31c990 error 4 in libguac-client-vnc.so.0.0.0[7fbfce7b2000+f000]
Jan 25 04:36:43 vnchost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 105232 (guacd) of user 0 killed by SIGSEGV - ignoring (repeated crash)
```

Application log here:

```
2019-01-25 12:32:58.441 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.guacamole.net.InetGuacamoleSocket    : Connecting to guacd at vnchost:4832.
2019-01-25 12:32:58.961 DEBUG 1 --- [       Thread-6] .g.b.g.w.e.MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint : Open tunnel on port: '5900', uuid: '2eba77c8-2f74-42a3-8ca5-4cf882ee3653' and connection_id: '$7d545e7e-0a29-40e5-a4a3-9964fa07b22b'.

2019-01-25 12:36:28.785 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.guacamole.net.InetGuacamoleSocket    : Connecting to guacd at vnchost:4832.
2019-01-25 12:36:29.137 DEBUG 1 --- [       Thread-8] .g.b.g.w.e.MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint : Open tunnel on port: '5902', uuid: '67446967-2e8e-42d7-9c73-68c2a80a270b' and connection_id: '$6fd98484-1dd0-4c66-aa04-6c358cd30548'.
2019-01-25 12:36:30.510 DEBUG 1 --- [       Thread-8] o.a.g.w.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint : Connection to guacd closed.

org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleConnectionClosedException: Connection to guacd is closed.
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.ReaderGuacamoleReader.read(ReaderGuacamoleReader.java:183) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint$2.run(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:160) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.ReaderGuacamoleReader.read(ReaderGuacamoleReader.java:169) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
 2019-01-25 12:36:30.511 DEBUG 1 --- [       Thread-8] .g.b.g.w.e.MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint : Close tunnel on port: '5902', uuid: '67446967-2e8e-42d7-9c73-68c2a80a270b' and connection_id: '$6fd98484-1dd0-4c66-aa04-6c358cd30548'.
2019-01-25 12:36:30.511 DEBUG 1 --- [       Thread-8] o.a.guacamole.net.InetGuacamoleSocket    : Closing socket to guacd.
2019-01-25 12:36:30.627 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.g.w.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint : Connection to guacd closed.

org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleConnectionClosedException: Connection to guacd is closed.
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.WriterGuacamoleWriter.write(WriterGuacamoleWriter.java:64) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.WriterGuacamoleWriter.write(WriterGuacamoleWriter.java:73) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.onMessage(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:221) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint$1.onMessage(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:129) [guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint$1.onMessage(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:125) [guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:394) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.sendMessageText(WsFrameServer.java:119) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:495) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:294) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.WriterGuacamoleWriter.write(WriterGuacamoleWriter.java:58) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        ... 22 common frames omitted

2019-01-25 12:36:33.068 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.g.w.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint : Connection to guacd closed.

org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleConnectionClosedException: Connection to guacd is closed.
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.WriterGuacamoleWriter.write(WriterGuacamoleWriter.java:64) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.WriterGuacamoleWriter.write(WriterGuacamoleWriter.java:73) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.onMessage(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:221) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint$1.onMessage(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:129) [guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.guacamole.websocket.GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint$1.onMessage(GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint.java:125) [guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:394) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.sendMessageText(WsFrameServer.java:119) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:495) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:294) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.guacamole.io.WriterGuacamoleWriter.write(WriterGuacamoleWriter.java:58) ~[guacamole-common-0.9.14.jar!/:na]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the root cause here.In my previous websocket implementation, I configured Spring container to use same instance to handle different websocket session, which in turn will handle different vnc connection. This seems caused the guacd to disconnect all socket connection from guacamole web server. 
By change to init a new EndPoint instance for each Websocket session, will resolved this.

The root cause is lying in the Guacamole's GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint extended by MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint.
 GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint use **tunnel** to store the current connection to the guacd process, if we initiate MyGuacamoleWebSocketEndPoint as **one** Bean in Spring and use it to handle all websocket sessions coming it, then it will cause unpredictable behavior as mentioned above.

```
@Override
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(final Session session, EndpointConfig config) {

    // Store underlying remote for future use via sendInstruction()
    remote = session.getBasicRemote();

    try {

        // Get tunnel
        **tunnel = createTunnel(session, config);**
        if (tunnel == null) {
            closeConnection(session, GuacamoleStatus.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

    }
    catch (GuacamoleException e) {
        logger.error("Creation of WebSocket tunnel to guacd failed: {}", e.getMessage());
        logger.debug("Error connecting WebSocket tunnel.", e);
        closeConnection(session, e.getStatus().getGuacamoleStatusCode(),
                e.getWebSocketCode());
        return;
    }
...}
```

Actually it's a typical instance sharing between different threads problem.

Guacamole's doc only give a sample to implement HttpServlet based application.
With websocket based application, we are on our own.

Comment: any change you could provide more details on how you fixed this. I've been experiencing the same issue and found no guide in the doc :/ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem

My class was something like this

```
ServerEndpoint(value = "/webSocket", configurator = CustomSpringConfigurator.class)
@Component

public class WebSocketTunnel extends GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelEndpoint {

    @Override
    protected GuacamoleTunnel createTunnel(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) throws GuacamoleException {
......
....
..
```

By just adding this spring annotation to the class, problem was solved, and can handle several websockets connections

```
@Scope("prototype")
```

This is because we are instantiating the websocket as a bean, and the default scope of a bean is singleton

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-scopes/

Note: take in mind that by using the prototype scope, you must handle the lifecycle of the bean by providing your own code.